# NodeJS crypto RSA, not compatible with Elixir/Erlang PublicKey?

Tags: node.js, elixir, rsa, public-key

I’m having trouble trying to decrypt in Elixir (using ExCrypto - which is a only a wrapper around crypto and public_key) encrypted by NodeJS Crypto.

Here’s what works :

- encrypt_public in NodeJS -> decrypt_private NodeJS (Works)
- encrypt_public in Elixir -> decrypt_pricate in Elixir (Works)

But :

- encrypt_public in NodeJS -> decrypt_private in Elixir (Does Not Work)

It seems that an encrypt_public from Node, can’t be decrypted by a decrypt_private in Elixir.
I even tried the hard way directly with the Erlang module public_key, it gives me the same result.

Here’s what I tried :

```
var fs = require("fs")
var crypto = require("crypto")

var rsa_key = fs.readFileSync('./priv/public.key').toString()
var rsa_priv = fs.readFileSync('./priv/private.key').toString()
var buffer = Buffer.from("Hello world")
var encrypted_auth = crypto.publicEncrypt({key: rsa_key}, buffer)
console.log("copy/paste this in iex: ", encrypted_auth.toString("Base64"))
var crypted_buffer = Buffer.from(encrypted_auth)
var decrypted_auth = crypto.privateDecrypt({key: rsa_priv, passphrase: "my_pass_phrase"}, crypted_buffer)
console.log("--- Res: ", decrypted_auth.toString())
```

But as soon as you copy/paste the Base64 generated in Node Here’s what I get :

```
key = ExPublicKey.load!("./priv/private.key", "my_pass_phrase")
cipher = "PASTED BASE64 FROM NODE"
ExPublicKey.decrypt_private(cipher, key)
```

returns `:error`

I have suspected the rsa padding to be different, but it doesn’t seems to be that… Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 2 issues
The padding by default in Node is : RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
while the default one is erlang is : rsa_pkcs1_padding

the solution is to modify the padding in Node :

```
var encrypted_auth = crypto.publicEncrypt({key: rsa_key, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, buffer)
```

The second issue, was that EXPublicKey was trying to Base.url_decode64 while the Base64 generated by Node is not url safe
To fix that :

```
ExPublicKey.decrypt_private(cipher, key, url_safe: false)
```